# Ensure a method implements an interface WITHOUT being an explicit implementation: is there a "EnsureImplementsInterface" ReSharper attribute?

Tags: c#, interface, resharper, typechecking

Given the following example code, I wish to be able to annotate that a method is absolutely expected to implement an interface.

```
interface X {
    void a(string x);
}

class Y : X {
    [EnsureImplementsInterface]
    public void a(string x) { .. }

    [EnsureImplementsInterface] // Should result in some form of "error"
    public void a(object x) { .. }
}
```

An explicit interface implementation is not suitable because the main usage will be via 'var' using statements; furthermore, changing to an explicit interface would break existing contracts.

The `override` keyword is not suitable/usable, because no method is being overridden and C# just doesn't work like that.

Comment: Instead of using an interface, use an abstract base class and roll on?

Comment: @Will In this *specific* case, that would work. However, if there is another restriction (eg multiple interfaces and not wishing to create a proxy base type) on a similar case in the future..

Comment: No, there is no such thing built into .NET, Visual Studio, or ReSharper. You can, however, create your own analyzers now, for Visual Studio 2017 (and 15?). This can do whatever you want, like look for that attribute and ensure it actually implements an interface.